# Изменение стиля ячейки таблицы при переносе строки текста

Tags: javascript, html, css

В таблице нужно реализовать такой механизм:

- Если в ячейке помещается строка текста *без переноса*, то для этой ячейки применяется один стиль;
- Если строка целиком не помещается, и текст *переносится* на вторую строку, то применяется другой стиль.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью CSS и JS? (Лучше чистый CSS.)

Comment: на чистом `css` нет, на `js`, лучше бросьте эту идею

Comment: @Dedotmoroz таблица сильно большая?

Comment: таблица большая и плюс подгружается динамически.

Comment: @Dedotmoroz данные записываются непосредственно в ячейки `td` или чем-то оборачиваются при вставке (`p`, `span` и т.п.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не зная всех вводных, трудно что-либо предполагать. Но способов тут не много, поэтому представлю два варианта:

### JS : правильно, но медленно...

**+** Можно стилями творить что угодно.
**–** При слишком большом количестве ячеек, может подтормаживать.
**–** Возможно мерцание ячеек во время их обхода.

К тому же, неизвестно, как поведёт себя этот способ, если в ячейках будут теги.

```js
/*
Функция добавления класса ячейке таблицы,
в случае обнаружения переноса текста.
*/
function fOverStringDetect() {
  // Проходим по всем "TD"
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector('.OverStringDetect').querySelectorAll('td')).forEach(function(oTD) {
    // Добавляем "редактируемость" в ячейках
    oTD.contentEditable = true; // Для примера (убрать после тестов)
    // Меняем стиль отображения ячейки с "table-cell" на "inline"
    oTD.style.display = 'inline';
    // Если количество "строк" больше, чем 1...
    (oTD.getClientRects().length > 1) ?
    // добавляем класс,
    oTD.classList.add('overload'):
      // иначе - удаляем
      oTD.classList.remove('overload');
    // Возвращаем ячейке стиль отображения "по умолчанию"
    oTD.style.display = '';
  });
}

window.onload = function() {

  /* Слушатель событий DOM */
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    fOverStringDetect();
  });
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('.OverStringDetect'), {
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  fOverStringDetect();
}
```

```css
table.OverStringDetect {
  border: 1px solid #080;
  width: 480px;
}

td {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.overload {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 20px red;
}
```

```html
<p>Попробуте изменить значения в ячейках:</p>
<table class="OverStringDetect">
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>12 345</td><td>12 3456 7890</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1 999999999</td><td>1234 5</td><td>12 345</td><td>12 3456 7890</td><td>1234 567890</td></tr>
  <tr><td>123 45</td><td>123 4567890</td><td>1 9 9 9 8</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td><td>1234 5</td><td>123 4567890</td><td>1 9 9 9 8</td><td>1234 567890</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1234 567890</td><td>1898 9090</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

### CSS : "обмануть судьбу"...

**+** CSS only. Только натив: один псевдоэлемент и пара свойств.
**±** Поведение предсказуемо и неизменно.
**–** Ооочень ограниченные возможности стилизации.

Возможно, такой способ вполне устроит, в виду своей простоты, но не устроит в плане дизайна и удобства зрительного восприятия.

```js
/*
Функция добавления всем ячейкам 
таблицы атрибута "contentEditable".
*/
function fAddEditableProp() {
  // Проходим по всем "TD"
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector('.OverStringDetect').querySelectorAll('td')).forEach(function(oTD) {
    // Добавляем "редактируемость" в ячейках
    oTD.contentEditable = true;
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  fAddEditableProp();
}
```

```css
table.OverStringDetect {
  border: 1px solid #080;
  width: 480px;
}

td {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  color: #f00;
}

td::first-line {
  color: #080;
}
```

```html
<p>Попробуте изменить значения в ячейках:</p>
<table class="OverStringDetect">
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>12 345</td><td>12 3456 7890</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1 999999999</td><td>1234 5</td><td>12 345</td><td>12 3456 7890</td><td>1234 567890</td></tr>
  <tr><td>123 45</td><td>123 4567890</td><td>1 9 9 9 8</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td><td>1234 5</td><td>123 4567890</td><td>1 9 9 9 8</td><td>1234 567890</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1234 567890</td><td>1898 9090</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 5</td><td>1234 567890</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

> *Все примеры интерактивны. Бо́льшую часть кода составляют комментарии и вспомогательные элементы (функции, стили и т.п.), и могут/должны быть удалены в реальном проекте.*

Comment: @ThisMan Если задача заключается только в визуальном контроле за появлением длинных строк, то такой простой вариант, думаю, приемлем. Но, если нужно и сами значения контролировать, то да - глаза сломаешь, даже с более щадящими цветами)) Это, как альтернатива - понятно же, что одним CSS тут много не наколдуешь).

Comment: getClientRects().length > 1 пока одно решение